# Relocate points in Delaunay triangulation

Tags: algorithm, optimization, computational-geometry, delaunay, voronoi

I just finished an implementation of the Delaunay's incremental flipping algorithm. This algorithm has a time complexity `O(N log N)`.

The application of the algorithm is based on taking each point as an antenna of a telephone company. Using the Delaunay's algorithm, I have to triangulate the space with such points then generate a Voronoi diagram using the triangulation in which each Voronoi polygon represents the coverage of each antenna

Now, I must solve the following problem:

> For each given point, and a constant `d`, relocate all the points in the plane, without exceeding the distance d from the original coordinates of each point, so that the Voronoi regions are maximized.

I can not imagine how to solve this problem with an efficient algorithm. Delaunay's and Voronoi's algorithms are already implemented.

Thanks!

Comment: Problem unclear. All Voronoi regions combined cover the entire plane (or whatever region in it they need to cover). The total area is fixed, however you move the points.

Comment: http://www.dma.fi.upm.es/mabellanas/antenas/aratm/memoria/doc_archivos/image002.gif

Comment: @n.m. this is the written in spanish http://www.dma.fi.upm.es/mabellanas/antenas/aratm/memoria/Objetivo.html

Comment: It looks like the objective is to make the cell areas as close to each other as possible. What exactly this means is still unclear but you can at least make educated guesses. You could e.g. minimize the standard deviation.

Comment: @n.m. the objective is to match as much as possible the area of the nearby regions. But, I can't find any algorithm to do it

Comment: "... con el objetivo de igualar lo más posible el área de sus regiones de proximidad" To me, that reads as if the areas of the Voronoi cells should be made equal, if possible. Perhaps a constrained variant of [Lloyd's algorithm](con el objetivo de igualar lo más posible el área de sus regiones de proximidad) can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Lloyd's algorithm. For each site compute the center of gravity and compare it with your old site. If the distance doesn't exceed the constant d relocate the site otherwise do nothing. Retriangulate the sites to smooth the mesh.

Comment: www.wikihow.com/Calculate-the-Center-of-Gravity-of-a-Triangle

Comment: Thanks!, but what happens if the voronoi region is not a triangle?

Comment: The voronoi is the dual of the delaunay triangulation. Voronoi edges outside the convex hull is normaly infinite. IMO it's not needed or not part of your question.

Comment: So, if I get the center of mass of a triangle in a Delaunay triangulation, then I have the center of mass of one region in the voronoi diagram

Comment: No. VD is the edge closest to a site then any other site. About Lloyd's algorithm:http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/

Comment: @ValentinaRamirez: You can find the centre of gravity of a Voronoi cell by averaging the centres of gravity of all triangles that are made up of the Voronoi edges and the reference point, weighted by their area: `cogV = sum(cog[i] * area[i]) / area[i]`

Comment: @MOehm:Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Phpdevpad: Elaborate what? That was just a (maybe unhelpful) remark to "but what happens if the voronoi region is not a triangle?"

Comment: @MOehm:sum(cog[i]*area[i]) is the sum of all triangles from the voronoi cell!? What is area[i] and why it is the denominator?

Comment: @MOehm What is the area[i] in the denominator?, the i index is in the sum or outside? and thank you!

Comment: Okay, typo: it must be `sum(area[i])` in the denominator. `area[i]` is the area of each triangle. `cog[i]` is the centre of gravity for each triangle as per the above link. Sorry if I confused you; I thought that calculating the COG was a problem. Otherwise, Lloyd's algo is straightforward if you already have the Voronoi triangulation code.

Comment: @ValentinaRamirez: If my answer is helpful please consider to accept it and/or upvote it. TY!

Comment: @ValentinaRamirez:It's also worth to mention the minimum spanning tree is a subset of the delaunay triangulation.